# React - Initialise state and access the state before first render

Tags: reactjs

I have the following issue.
I would like to initialise the state of my main component App where one of the state properties has to access another one.

Doing the following I get the this error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined.

```
 class App extends Component {
  state = {
    items: [
        'itemOne',
        'itemTwo',
    ],
    currentItem: this.state.items[0]
}
```

I assume that the state was not set yet, thus the items array doesn't exist.
Setting the state of currentItem using componentDidMount() may solve the problem but then other errors might occur because currenItem is passed as prop to other components.

What is the most elegant, standard way you managing this?

Comment: Where is the `items` array coming from? Props? Const value in class file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it in the constructor:

```
 class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const items =  [
        'itemOne',
        'itemTwo',
    ]
    this.state = {
    items: items,
    currentItem: items[0];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the state's value to another state before rendering.
In this case, You can use the lifecycle `componentDidMount()`.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    items: ['itemOne', 'itemTwo'],
    currentItem: 'itemOne' || null //You can define the initial value or null
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    setState({...this.state, currentItem: this.state.items[0]});
  }
```